# The cardinality of the minimal generating set of $G = \mathbb{Z}_2^m$ is $\log_2 |G|$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Referring to this thread [Click Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226931/why-is-the-minimum-size-of-a-generating-set-for-a-finite-group-at-most-log-2-n)

It is proven there that the minimum size of a generating set for a finite group at most $\log_2 |G|$?

In the answer, it is noted without a proof that:

> The cardinality of the minimal generating set of $G = \mathbb{Z}_2^m$ is $\log_2 |G|$

Can anyone explain why is that true?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Think of $\mathbb{Z}_2^m$ as an $m$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Then, a minimum generating set really is a basis.

Comment: How does that help me show the result?

Comment: @UmShmum The minimum cardinality for that minimal generator would then be $m$ and the answer you referred showed that the maximum value is $m$ too. So, it must  be equal to $m$ then.

Comment: How do you show that the dimension of the basis is greater than $m$?

Comment: @UmShmum What do you mean? Since this is an $m$ dimensional vector space, the cardinality of the basis is $m$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how do you show that this is an $m$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: @UmShmum Because the set $\{(1,0,...,0),(0,1,...,0),...,(0,0,...,1)\}$ is a basis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90834/discussion-between-um-shmum-and-sintan1729).

Comment: Alternatively, since the group is abelian with exponent $2$, you could show that a subset of size $k$ generates a subgroup of order at most $2^k$. Hence to generate the whole group we must have $k \ge m$.